SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided, S3 connection
I am new in Go and AWS and have been trying for almost a week to connect to a local deployment of S3 to no avail. I am currently using the AWS-SDK v1 for Go and are trying to create a simple connection to the endpoint so that I can list the contents of a bucket. I have simple client setup with set credentials but every time, I get either an authentication error, or DNS resolution error. Can anyone help please?
I've tried several different ways of specifying the credentials (credentials file, environment variables, setting env vars in the golang program) but still get the same error.  yet when I use them in Python it works with no issue. I have read  similar cases but none of the solutions seem to work for me
Below is my code
package main
 
import (
    "fmt"
 
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)
 
type S3Client struct {
    url        string
    accessKey  string
    secretKey  string
    bucketName string
    //httpClient *http.Client
}
 
func NewClient(endpointUrl, accessKey, secretKey, bucketName string) (S3Client, error) {
 
    justS3 := S3Client{
        url:        endpointUrl,
        accessKey:  accessKey,
        secretKey:  secretKey,
        bucketName: bucketName,
    }
    return justS3, nil
}
 
func (c *S3Client) ListBucketContents() {
 
    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(c.accessKey, c.secretKey, "")
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
 
        Credentials: creds,
        Endpoint:    aws.String(c.url),
        Region:      aws.String("us-east-01"),
        DisableSSL:  aws.Bool(true),
    })
 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to login, due to error %v", err)
    }
 
    //create an s3 service client
    svc := s3.New(sess)
 
    //get list of all items
 
    resp, err := svc.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{Bucket:
                                                             aws.String(c.bucketName)})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to list items in bucket %q, %v,", c.bucketName, err)
    }
 
    for _, item := range resp.Contents {
 
        fmt.Printf("Below is a list of Items under the bucket %s .\n", c.bucketName)
        fmt.Print("*********************************")
        fmt.Println("Name:             ", item.Key)
        fmt.Print("Last Modified", item.LastModified)
        fmt.Print("Size", item.Size)
        fmt.Println("")
 
    }
 
}

package main
 
import (
    "fmt"
)
 
func main() {
 
    client, err := NewClient("<endpoint>", "Accesskey", "SecretKey", "bucketname")
 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("The logging has failed")
 
    }
 
    client.ListBucketContents()
 
}


AWS has announced end-of-support for AWS SDK for Go V1 and recommends to migrate to AWS SDK for Go V2.
With V2 you would do:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    bucketName := "..."
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Using the SDK's default configuration, loading additional config
    // and credentials values from the environment variables, shared
    // credentials, and shared configuration files
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithRegion("us-east-01"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load SDK config, %v", err)
    }

    // Using the Config value, create the S3 client
    svc := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    // Build the request with its input parameters
    resp, err := svc.ListObjectsV2(ctx, &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to list objects, %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Below is a list of Items under the bucket %s.\n", bucketName)
    fmt.Println("*********************************")
    for _, item := range resp.Contents {
        fmt.Println("Name:", item.Key)
        fmt.Println("Last Modified:", item.LastModified)
        fmt.Println("Size:", item.Size)
        fmt.Println()
    }
}


Thank you.  I though the SDK might be a problem . Unfortunately, v2 requires me to get Go 1.21 version which I can't yet install in my work environment, hence why I used SDK v1. Mostly having a version issue with the package github.com/aws/smithy-go v1.22.1 .  is there a version that is compatible with Go 1.20?

Yes, v1.30.3.

Found the solution by setting the S3ForcePathStyle field to true on the Config struct,  and removing the V2 reference in my functions.
resp, err := svc.ListObjects(&s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: aws.String(c.bucketName)}).
It's pretty weird but the are a lot of ssl authentication issues with V1. will close the case now
